# How to import/check the sparkcontext created in one py file to another?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark. Presently I am trying to extract Facebook API data by using Pyspark. I am creating sparkcontext in the main file which I am calling. I have multiple.py files in the folder where all these get executed when I do spark submit the main program.

When the program goes to other .py files, I want to check whether the sparkcontext that i have created is present or not. If yes, I want to use that sparkcontext for execution of other.py files. Can any one help me the way of doing this. If I am wrong any where. Please suggest the best idea.

Example:This is not my entire code just showing my problem with small code

```
# Calling file name: main_file.py        
def fb_calling():
       import file2
       file2.fb_generaldata()

f __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName('fb_sapp')
    conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    fb_calling()

# File:file2.py
def fb_generaldata():
    sc.parallelize('path')
```

My problem is i want to use the sparkcontext that created in main_file.py to be used in file2.py
Can you tell how is that possible.If i am on wrong track can you guide me correctly. I am totally new to spark.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the sparkContex as an argument to your function in file2.py like this

```
# File:file2.py
def fb_generaldata(sc):
    sc.parallelize('path')

# main_file.py 
import file2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName('fb_sapp')
    conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    file2.fb_generaldata(sc)
```

Depending on how you are running it you might need to send the file to your workers before importing, you can do that with `sc.addPyFile("file2.py")` or with the `py-files` argument in your spark-submit command.

Comment: Thanks for the info...i have tried your code sample...its working...Thank u